# Magento overwrite Controller init method

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

I tried to overwrite Controller with [these instructions](http://prattski.com/2010/06/24/magento-overriding-core-files-blocks-models-resources-controllers/), but they only worked for Action methods, but not any others. Is it possible to override Controller _init() method?

Comment: I couldn't find any help and I'm in hurry, so I just edited module files, now I have to merge those when module is updated, but at least it worked. Still if somebody knows how you can override controller init methods, it would be good to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are extending the correct file. This method does work. Tested with the CustomerController. Will repost my code:

config.xml:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <module>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Company_Module</module>
                <frontName>module</frontName>
            </args>
        </module>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <module before="Mage_Adminhtml">Company_Module</module>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Company/Module/controllers/CustomerController.php:

```
<?php
include_once("Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php");
class Company_Module_CustomerController extends Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController
{
    protected function _initCustomer($idFieldname = 'id')
    {
        Mage::log('overridden');
        parent::_initCustomer($idFieldname);
    } 
}
```

Note the include, note that it extends the controller `Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController` **NOT** `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action`, and also, note that the `_initCustomer()` function is protected, that probably is what is holding you up.